# how to store real and complex types of same precision in a parameterized type definition

Tags: types, julia

In our code, we have both real and complex arrays which should be of the same precision that we'd like to wrap in a parameterized type. Something along the lines of the following would be great:

```
type NewType{T<:Union{Complex{Float32},Complex{Float64}}}
    a::T
    b::real(T)
end
```

The above is not allowed. In julia v0.6 I get

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching real(::TypeVar)
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

edit:

Turns out

`type NewType{T<:Union{Float32,Float64}}
    a::Complex{T}
    b::T
end`

Accomplishes what I want. But I'd still be interested in what the correct julian approach is

Comment: I would do it like you proposed except now in Julia you should use word `mutable struct` instead of `type` and it is enough to write struct `NewType{T}` and let the constructor of `Complex` decide what types of `T` it accepts. Or use `AbstractFloat` instead of union to restrict yourself to floats (then you can accept e.g. `BigFloat` if you would need a higher precision).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didn't know that "type" was deprecated. I would actually like to completely restrict things to BLAS friendly types like the above. I may actually just define the types and functions programmatically in the end, imitating the style of BLAS.jl

Comment: Your own solution is fine. You could also use `NewType{T, S<:Complex{T}}`, but that's no more elegant. Consider whether you need mutability, an (immutable) `struct` can have significantly better performance. Also, I strongly suggest that you _not_ restrict types to Float32/64. Don't restrict types without a really good reason, you never know what other people (or you yourself) might like to use the code for in the future. Making code generic is very much in the spirit of Julia, and there is nothing to lose by doing it.